# Compute F1-Score inside Validation Step

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp

I am fine-tuning the mT5 model for QA.

I am using PyTorch Lightning, and currently, my validation step looks like this:

```
  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch['input_ids']
    attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']
    labels = batch['labels']
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log('val_loss', loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss
```

Instead of logging the `val_loss` and choosing the best checkpoint based on that, I want to calculate the F1-Score, and choose the best checkpoint based on the best overall F1.

I successfully calculated the predictions after the training loop is completed:

```
predictions = []
ground_truths = []
for batch in tqdm(data_module.test_dataloader(), desc="Evaluating"):
    input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(DEVICE)
    attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(DEVICE)
    labels = batch['labels'].to(DEVICE)
    with torch.no_grad():
        generated_ids = trained_model.model.generate(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
        )

    predicted_answers = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
    predictions.extend(predicted_answers)

    mask = labels != -100
    labels = torch.masked_select(labels, mask)
    true_text = tokenizer.decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
    ground_truths.append(true_text)
```

How can I compute the prediction / ground_truth inside the validation step in order to compute the F1-Score there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your actual predictions and outputs are, but I recommend this function for n-D F1-score calculator, using flatten and confusion matrix.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def f1_score_calc(np_pred, np_gt,):
    f1m = []

    epsilon = 2.22045e-16

    for i in range(np_pred.shape[0]):
        label = np_gt[i, :, :]
        pred = np_pred[i, :, :]
        label = label.flatten()
        pred = pred.flatten()

        try:
            tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true=label, y_pred=pred).ravel()
        except ValueError: # exception for all-zero
            tn, fp, fn, tp = 0, 0, 0, 0
        sensitivity = tp / (tp + fn + epsilon)
        precision = tp / (tp + fp + epsilon)
        f1_score = (2 * sensitivity * precision) / (sensitivity + precision + epsilon)

        f1m.append(f1_score)

    return np.array(f1m).mean()
```

Notice that the 'np_pred' and 'np_gt' are shape of (N, H, W) in np.ndarray, and elements are formatted with argmax value.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate batch-wise f1 score in the evalution step using this code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
  input_ids = batch['input_ids']
  attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']
  labels = batch['labels']
  loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
  prediction = outputs.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
  f1 = f1_score(labels, prediction)
  self.log('val_loss', loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
  return loss
```